# Heatmap vs image function in R

Tags: r, function, cluster-analysis

I just noticed that the plots from using `heatmap()` function and `image()` function look different even though I'm using the same data matrix. I have the following code:

```
set.seed(12345)
dataMatrix <- matrix(rnorm(400), nrow =40)

set.seed(678910)
for(i in 1:40) {
# flip a coin
coinFlip <- rbinom(1, size =1, prob =0.5)
# if coin is heads add a common pattern to that row
if(coinFlip) {
dataMatrix[i, ] <- dataMatrix[i, ] + rep(c(0,3), each =5)
}}

hh <- hclust(dist(dataMatrix))
dataMatrixOrdered <- dataMatrix[hh$order, ]
image(t(dataMatrixOrdered)[, nrow(dataMatrixOrdered):1])
heatmap(t(dataMatrixOrdered)[, nrow(dataMatrixOrdered):1])
```

As far as I have understood, the only difference between the 2 functions is that, the `heatmap()` function does a cluster analysis to produce dendrograms for rows and columns. Hence the plots should look the same. Can someone please tell me why I see this difference? I have attached the plots from the 2 functions.[image: Plot using heatmap][image: Plot using image]

Comment: heatmap also reorders rows & columns by default; see the help page

Comment: Please tell us what the diff is.  As BenB points out , different plotting routines orient the axes differently.  Is this your concern, or do you have a spatial resolution issue, or a contrast issue, etc.?

Comment: I tried using the arguments Rowv =NA, Colv=NA which the R help page says that no reordering would be done but I think only the dendrograms are suppressed but ordering still takes place it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the two functions produce consistently different patterns. I have no idea how that happens, but this happens whether you reorder the data or not.

Just to facilitate visualizing the differences, I turned dataMatrix into a distance matrix. The heatmap displaying this distance matrix should be fully symetrical. Image does give a symetric heatmap, heatmap does not.

```
set.seed(12345)
dataMatrix <- matrix(rnorm(400), nrow =40)

set.seed(678910)
for(i in 1:40) {
# flip a coin
coinFlip <- rbinom(1, size =1, prob =0.5)
# if coin is heads add a common pattern to that row
if(coinFlip) {
dataMatrix[i, ] <- dataMatrix[i, ] + rep(c(0,3), each =5)
}}

dataMatrix <- as.matrix(dist(dataMatrix))

image(dataMatrix)

heatmap(dataMatrix, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

What happens is that heatmap is scaling the rows before doing the coloring. If you avoid this scaling, the two functions give the same heatmap.

```
heatmap(dataMatrix, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale = "none")
```

You can read more about this [here](https://rpubs.com/crazyhottommy/a-tale-of-two-heatmap-functions)